# Execute macro commands in csv files or create a macro that transforms the file into csv

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file with a table of info and information about the entry. In the table I have columns, one column in the table is the social security number, the ID number in my country is 9 digits. Often the ID number begins with a 0 - digit number. The Excel always omits the number 0, I wrote a macro code that adds 0. But I end up converting the file to CSV, after converting it again omits the number 0. I want to know how I execute my macro code in CSV (which disappeared 0 - I will be happy to set up the macro on csv files or at least execute a macro that converts the file into a .csv file and saves the 0 that disappear. Here is my command that works on xslm:

```
Sub Add_Zeros()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each CL In Selection.Cells
        If CL <> "" Then CL.Value = Application.Rept("0", (9 - Len(CL))) & CL
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Csv will have the `0`. You can check that by opening it in notepad. If you double click on the CSV and open it in Excel then the `0s` will disappear.

To preserve the `0s`, you will have to import the data directly in Excel. Follow the steps mentioned below.

1. Click on Data Tab | From Text
2. Select the Csv from the file slection dialog box
3. In text Import Wizard (STEP 1), select 'Delimited' and hit next.
4. In text Import Wizard (STEP 2), select 'Comma' and hit next.
5. In text Import Wizard (STEP 3), select all columns and click on 'text' in the 'column data format'
6. Click finish
7. Select the cell where you want to import the data and click 'ok'

Comment: Does not work, i tried exactly what you suggested i can send you the file and try it on you.
Thank you

Comment: forstackoverflowexamples@gmail.com